# Corona Touch Listener

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I am learning corona sdk
This is the following code
when the two objects overlaps it becomes 1 objects(Moves together), i have no clue whats going on...

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--
-- main.lua
--
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

-- Your code here
local physics = require( "physics" )
physics.start()

local crate1 = display.newImage( "crate.png", display.contentCenterX, 100 )
crate1.name = "crate1"
local crate2 = display.newImage( "crate.png", display.contentCenterX + 100, 100 )
crate2.name = "crate2"
crate1:scale(0.2, 0.2)
crate2:scale(0.2, 0.2)

local bodyTouched = function(event)

            if(crate1.name == event.target.name and event.phase == "moved")
                then
                    print("Moved " , event.target.name )
                    crate1.x = event.x
                    crate1.y = event.y
            elseif (crate2.name == event.target.name and event.phase == "moved")
                then
                    print( "Moved ", event.target.name )
                    crate2.x = event.x
                    crate2.y = event.y
            end 


end 



physics.addBody( crate1, "static")
physics.addBody( crate2, "static")

crate1:addEventListener( "touch", bodyTouched )
crate2:addEventListener( "touch", bodyTouched )
```

Comment: what do you mean by "become 1"? I assume they just move together? how do you know it is one object?

Comment: yes yes they move together but i want to avoid it...

Comment: then you got too fat fingers :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please refer to the Corona SDK documentation.
https://docs.coronalabs.com/daily/guide/events/detectEvents/index.html#TOC

Section: Understanding Hit Events

In general you should read the documentation on anything you use. 
Your touch event will propagate through all display objects that intersect with the event coordinate. The event will trigger all registered event listeners on its way.

To avoid having multiple listeners triggered your event listener `bodyTouch` has to return `true` which will tell Corona that you handled the event and no further listeners should be invoked.